# Select Only one data from the table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi guys I have this data from my table
[image]

details_ID |  Author | DetailTitle | DetailDescription | DateCreated | DateUpdated

---

12                 |admin   |      Test      |      Just a test       |   12/5/2012   | 12/5/2012

13                 |admin   |      Test2     |      Dog vs cat       |   12/5/2012   | 12/5/2012

14                 |admin   |      Test3     |      blah blah        |   12/5/2012   | 12/5/2012


I'm calling them in my view as a list

```
public ViewResult Index()

        {
            return View(db.ProjectDetails.ToList());
        }
```

and my view

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectXYZ.Models.ProjectDetail>`


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }


<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>


<table>
     <tr>      
       <th>Author</th>

       <th>DetailTitle</th>

       <th>DetailDescription</th>

       <th>DateCreated</th>

       <th>DateUpdated</th>
       <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DetailTitle)</td>
        <td>@Html.Raw(item.DetailDescription)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateCreated)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateUpdated)</td>

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.details_ID }) |           
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.details_ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
  } 
</table>
```

**Problem**: I just want to view a single item in my view with details_ID = 12

I know I have to do some querying here on my controller but don't know how..

I appreciate any help.. :)

Comment: I can't see your image... is there a way to post the data in textual format?

Comment: @LeviBotelho: I've changed it already

Comment: @VahidND: I tried do the coding myself but not successful.. I know I have to do some querying on its controller but I don't know how.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an instant result you can try this:

```
return View(db.ProjectDetails.Where(p => p.details_ID == 12).ToList());
```

but you should filter it as you fetch data from the database.

Comment: your comment also works dude I'll give the point on your post.. :) thanks for helping..

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.details_ID }) </td> </tr> }
```

Out of the scope of foreach, so item is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work guys. I added this query on my controller:

```
{
var pd = 
       (from ProjectDetail in db.ProjectDetails
       where ProjectDetail.details_ID == 12
       select ProjectDetail
       )
       .ToList();
return View(pd);
}
```

-still thanks to the people who tried to help me.. :)